# Are temporary variables a thing & do the dispose faster?

Tags: c#, variables, memory

I have no idea how to phrase this correctly so please bear with me. Working in C# .NET, I inherit a class which contains a function which returns an object for unmanaged functions. When I use the inherited function directly the unmanaged task fails. If I create a reference to the object returned by the inherited function and call the unmanaged function from the referenced object it works.

**Pseudo .NET code example:**

```
public class A {
  void UnmanagedFunc() {...}
}

public class B {
  public A GetA() {
    return new A();
  }
}

public class C : B {
  public void DoSomething() {
    this.GetA().UnmanagedFunc();
  }
}

public class D : B {
  public void DoSomething() {
    var a = this.GetA();
    a.UnmanagedFunc();
  }
}
```

You can see the functions in class C and D are equivalent but D declares a reference to the object instantiated by the base class function.

My collegues say that declaring the variable gives the unmanaged process time to complete because the object of the variable still needs to be disposed where the object that is directly accessed is disposed immediately.

This makes some sense but I don't find this a satisfactory answer.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: And the programming language you're talking about is...?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from the internet. I'm working in C#

Comment: "It fails" is not an appropriate problem description.  Use the unmanaged debugger to troubleshoot issues with unmanaged code.  If you don't have the source code then the proper tool to use is a telephone.

Comment: Pseudocode is not going to help here.

Comment: I tried abstracting the code because it's deep in a framework built for Dynamics CRM. The unmanaged function updates a CRM entity using a Web Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know why this:

> ```
> this.GetA().UnmanagedFunc();
> ```

fails, while this:

> ```
> var a = this.GetA();
> a.UnmanagedFunc();
> ```

does not.

Well, let me say this: at least in a non-debug build, where the compiler and runtime (specifically, the JIT code generator) are allowed to apply optimizations, your local variable `a` might simply be optimized away, so you should for all practical purposes assume that both versions of your code are functionally identical.

In such a simple example as you have given, a local variable has only one advantage: it gives you the means to "name" or describe the object returned by `GetA()`; for example, you could call the local variable `aForFrobbling`, `lastUsedA`, or whatever.

> *"My collegues say that declaring the variable gives the unmanaged process time to complete because the object of the variable still needs to be disposed where the object that is directly accessed is disposed immediately."*

I would not accept that argument, mostly because it appears that your colleagues have some wrong ideas about .NET memory management.

1. It is not *variables* that are disposed, but *objects* that are no longer referenced by said variables (or anything else, such as fields or parameters).
2. Garbage collection (GC) in .NET is non-deterministic. Just because a variable goes out of scope does not mean that the object last referenced by it gets reclaimed immediately. Objects (at least those on the heap) continue to live at least up to when the next GC runs (whenever that is); whether they are referenced by a variable / field / parameter or not. The only reason that can lead to an object being reclaimed is that it is no longer referenced by anything; but you do not know when GC will kick in (unless you explicitly trigger it).
3. Terminology: "Disposal" in .NET strongly suggests that the object in question is of a type that implements `IDisposable`. Judging from your code example, that doesn't seem to be the case here.

That being said, perhaps we don't see all of your code that is relevant. Where is there any "disposal" involved? Does your unmanaged code keep running in the background (i.e. in a separate thread) and do things to your .NET objects that the .NET garbage collector cannot know about? And anyway, how can an unmanaged function (`UnmanagedFunc`) be a method on a managed object? Many questions. I feel I cannot fully answer your question besides what I said above.

Just one thing: If you do need to give some unmanaged code time before you dispose your object, then you should re-think your program's design. Make the timing explicit, don't rely on tricks that work only sometimes (and even then, you don't know why): The unmanaged code should offer you the means to ask it whether it is done; be it through callback functions, or some event mechanism. If so, make sure that your .NET object cannot be freed by the garbage collector before that by extending its lifetime scope (for instance by storing the object in a class field instead of in a local variable); or check out the possibilities offered to you by the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class.

Comment: Thanks, I also don't accept the argument, hence I posted on Stackoverflow. But I think I need to dig a little deeper to give empirical evidence of what is happening.